# zsh: "unknown file attribute" when adding an item to an array in a for loop

Tags: arrays, loops, scripting, zsh

What is the proper format for adding an element to an array in `zsh` when using a `for` loop and variables?

When I try to run

```
declare -a $numbers

for i in {1..5}
do
  $numbers+=($i)
done
```

I get `unknown file attribute: 1`.

Comment: The simplest would be `numbers+=$i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on this in another context, I discovered that I'm not supposed to use `$` when referencing the array. Instead of

```
$numbers+=($i)
```

I need to use

```
numbers+=($i)
```

**Edit**
Per the comment by @chepner, I was also declaring the array on `$numbers` instead of `numbers`. This didn't cause any obvious issues with this particular example because that variable didn't already exist, but I can see it causing problems in more complex situations.

Comment: `declare -a numbers` as well. `declare -a $numbers` tries to set the array attribute on a variable whose name is produced by the expansion of `$numbers`, not on the name `numbers` itself.

Comment: As for the actual error, `$numbers+=($i)` is not an assignment because `$numbers` is not a valid identifier. Thus, the result of expanding `$numbers+=` is subject to filename generation with the expansion of `$i` as a glob qualifier. (If all these expansions succeeded, the final result would be treated as the name of a command to execute.)